# Trying up update cart with Javascript Php and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to select an item from an array to push into the shopping cart via an ajax call but my JS skills are a little weak and need some pointers;

Heres ht js

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
var element = $(this).closest('.items');
var image = element.find('img')[0].src;
var name = element.find('input').val();
var price=document.find('input').val();

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'store_items.php',
    data:{
      item_src:img_src,
      item_name:name,
      item_price:price
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

}

function show_cart()
{
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'store_items.php',
  data:{
    showcart:"cart"
  },
  success:function(response) {
    document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;
    $("#mycart").slideToggle();
  }
 });

}
```

This is the while loop to spit out the list of products

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    echo '
    <div class="items" id="item">
    <a href="doc_view.php?prod_id='.$row["prod_id"].'"> '.$row["prod_name"]. '</a>';

    echo "
    <div class='product_display'>
    <p><img src='../admin/uploads/".$row['file_upload']."'></p>";    


   echo"
    <input type='button' value='Add To CART' id='cart_button' onclick='cart(\"item\");' "; 

    echo'
    <p>Price - '.$row["prod_price"]. '</p>
    <input type="hidden" class="item_name" value="'.$row["prod_name"]. '">
    <input type="hidden" class="item_price" value="'.$row["prod_price"]. '">';?>

    <?php echo'
    </div>
    </div>
    ';


    }
```

I am struggling to get the products to show in the cart - I display it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'store_items.php',
    data:{
      total_cart_items:"totalitems"
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

});


<p id="cart_button" onclick="show_cart();">
  <input type="button" id="total_items" value="">
</p>

<div id="mycart">
</div>

<a href="../index.php">home</a>
<div id="item_div">
```

Comment: Why do you switch *out* of jQuery for the success function? Could easily be `$('#total_items').html(response);` Have you watched the browser's console during the request / response process?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah im getting some annoying error saying im missing a `)` but where it suggest the line I do not believe it is right.... I am adding it in but keep getting it - I think my code above is not right to be honest but I struggle with JS

Comment: @JayBlanchard the problem I have it does not add the items form the array to the cart - is it the element.find that may be letting me down?

Comment: Looks like you didn't close your `click` function properly. It ends with a `}`. But it should be `});`